# TFS build does not copy Cordova project output

Tags: cordova, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on a Cordova project developed with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. I have created a TFS build definition (I'm using TFS 2013) for the project that is able to build the project. I get the correct output, but this output is not copied to the specified dropped location or anywhere else.

I have tried a lot of things and nothing worked. I believe it must be related to the fact that the *.jsproj* does not define and `OutputType` or an `OutputPath` for any configuration.

In the build definition for **Staging location** in **Build defaults** I have selected *Copy build output to the following drop folder*. All I get there is the logs.

See the image below. the **src** folder contains the sources and after the build the output of the Cordova build (**bin** and **bld**). However, I'd expect the content from **bin\Android\Release** to be copied to the upper level **bin** folder (as seen in the picture) and eventually on the drop location. This does not happen.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PowerShell script to get this to work.

```
$packages = gci $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY -recurse -include $("bin") | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | foreach { gci -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -include $("*.apk", "*.ipa", "*.plist", "*.xap") }
foreach ($file in $packages) {
    Copy $file $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY
}
gci $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY -recurse -include $("AppPackages") | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Copy -Destination $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY –Recurse -Force
```

Put this in a solution folder in the solution root so that it doesn't get added to the app package and check this in with your solution.

Then in your TFS build definition add a "Post-build script" that points to this script.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. It would be great if this was supported through the VS tools for Cordova or MSBuild so we don't have to work around with scripts like this.

Comment: TFS 2015 and Visual Studio Online will be introducing a next-generation build system that will better enable Cordova builds thanks to a cross-platform build agent.  Stay tuned for more information. Here is some info from the Feb CTP: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-vs.aspx