# No IPA output for Cordova build in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, build, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing a mobile app with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 in VS 2013. I have configured everything according to the MSDN specifications here [Install Tools to Build for iOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx). I am able to build the app and run the remote simulator (as described here [Run Your Apache Cordova App on iOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757056.aspx)).

My problem is there is no output from the build back on the Windows machine where I have Visual Studio. More than that, there is no *.ipa* file created on the Mac either. I can find the build at */Users//remote-builds/builds/* but that's all. I can open the project in XCode for instance, but that's not what I want.

I want the final package file that I can install on test devices and eventually publish to the store. How do I get that?

Also my goal is to setup a TFS build definition so I can get a build each time I commit changes. I need to get that output file to the drop location of my build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within VS, you will have to choose "Remote Device" or "Local Device" as your debug target and then "build" to get an IPA back.

Also, refer to  [TFS build does not copy Cordova project output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818324/tfs-build-does-not-copy-cordova-project-output) for instructions on how to setup TFS for CI workflow.

Comment: This is weird, because I don't have a local or remote device. I find it very strange the way VS and MSBuild use the debugger as the selection for what to build. This `DebuggerFlavor` property for MSBuild that is set from the selected debugger.

Comment: The requirement for pointing the build to a device is Apple XCode's.  It does not build deployable .ipa file with distribution profile unless its target is an _iOS device_ and not a simulator.  Visual Studio is just setting the XCode values to match what set in VS.

Comment: OK, I can understand that, but I find it confusing that the target is selected through the type of the debugger.