# Provisioning profile not being accepted?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a IPA from my cordova-ionic project using visual studio 2015. I can run the project on an iOS simulator using remotebuild.

I have followed the steps [here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) and created a provisioning profile (using my free Apple ID). I am in a tricky situation and the iOS device that I would like to run the project on is in a different country.

I'm creating the provisioning profile on my friend's mac with the iOS device attached. I am then logging into an El Capitan VM on my machine and using the provisioning profile generated on my friend's mac to attempt to create an IPA. I am following what is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921739/no-ipa-output-for-cordova-build-in-visual-studio) and running the project on visual studio using debug and remote device or local device.

I get the following error:

```
Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command:
xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BookYourTutor.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BookYourTutor,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1    BookYourTutor       1
```

Looking at the output from build, towards the end, i see:

```
Libtool /Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a normal armv7
cd /Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Users/noyolk/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/noyolk/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/2.2.1/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/node_modules/ios-sim/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" 
/Users/noyolk/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Users/noyolk/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -L/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device -filelist /Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cordova.LinkFileList -o /Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a 

=== BUILD TARGET BookYourTutor OF PROJECT BookYourTutor WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies 
Signing for "BookYourTutor" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. 
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Failed to build app for buildNumber 708: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BookYourTutor.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BookYourTutor,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BookYourTutor.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BookYourTutor,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1
Error Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BookYourTutor.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BookYourTutor,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/noyolk/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/708/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - {1}
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

With what I believe to be the most important bit being,

```
=== BUILD TARGET BookYourTutor OF PROJECT BookYourTutor WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
Signing for "BookYourTutor" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly this means or how I should fix it. For context, I'm using xcode 8 beta 4 on my El Capitan VM.

I've tried searching around for this 'error code 65' and the error message 'Signing for XXX requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.' but have not had much luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you add developer account in the Projects -> Targets -> General?

Comment: did not get a chance to try it i'm afraid. i downgraded to xcode 7 and the issue went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to xcode 7 from xcode 8 beta 4 seems to have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change due to the release of iOS 10.

Reference https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html for a workaround.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, and I followed the instructions in the dpogue article, and it hasn't helped at all. I'm using the release version of xcode (8.0)

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do some trial and error. The above link helped a lot, but the issues were still with what Apple was needing for XCode 8 to accept the build request. My settings in build.json are similar to this:

```
"ios": {
  "debug": {
   "developmentTeam": "[my team id]",
   "provisioningProfile: "[my provisioning profile]"
  },
  "release": {
   "developmentTeam": "[my team id]",
   "provisioningProfile: "[my provisioning profile]"
  }
 }
}
```

To get your developmentTeam, log into developer.apple.com, click on Membership, and you will see your TEAM ID. Put that in as the developmentTeam.

For the provisioningProfile, open XCode --> Preferences, click on your profile, View Details. Click on your provisioning profile, right click, and Show in Finder. Your provisioning profile is the entire file name, minus the .mobileprovision file extension. Save build.json, rebuild your project, and you should be good to go.